# Javascript - Remove year and write full weekday name in date name

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use JavaScript to write the date TWO days from now. I'd prefer to show the full weekday name, and not show the year. For example, right now the code I have writes:

"Fri May 08 2020"

and I'd like it to say:

"Friday, May 08"

The script I have is:

```
<script>
var days = 2;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24*60*60*1000).toDateString();
document.write(newDate);
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by using [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) method and passing some parameter to the `options` object like:

```js
var days = 2;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  .toLocaleDateString(undefined, { weekday: 'long',month: 'long',day: '2-digit' });
document.write(newDate);
//=> Friday, May 08
```

Few things here:

- `weekday: 'long'` is used to display weekday in long-form like `Friday` instead of `Fri`.
- `day: '2-digit'` is used to display date like `08` instead of `8`.

You can see without passing these options date will be displayed like:

```js
var days = 2;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toLocaleDateString();
document.write(newDate);
//=> 5/8/2020
```

Comment: Yes, that is also one of the solutions. Thanks for sharing that info.